# Correlation values from match_template

Tags: python, image

I am writing a script to locate the position of an image cutout in a bigger image (problem similar to what described [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_template.html)). To do so, I am using `match_template`, part of `skimage`. I also want to look at the correlation values (I suppose it should be a matrix, and that `match_template` takes the maximum); how could I get them?

This is the code I am using:

```
cutout = np.loadtxt(filename_cutout.txt)
image = np.loadtxt(filename_image.txt)
array_cutout = np.array(cutout)
array_image = np.array(image)
result = match_template(image, cutout)
ij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(result), result.shape)
x, y = ij[::-1]
ran = array_cutout.shape
ran_y = ran[1]
ran_x = ran[0]
x_center = x + (ran_x/2)
y_center = y + (ran_y/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

skimage.features.match_template takes your image of shape (M,N) and a template of shape (m,n), and returns a response image containing the correlation coefficients of shape (M-m+1, N-n+1).  The highest value in that response corresponds to the most likely match in the image.

```
ij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(result), result.shape)
```

The line `np.argmax(result)` returns the highest value in the response image, which should correspond to the location of your template.

Is there a reason you're loading the image from a .txt file?  When I've used match_template, I typically use `skimage.io.imread()` to load the image into an array.  Then I can binarize it, or gray scale it, which sometimes returns better results.